# Comparing array values with each other

Tags: c#

I want to compare two integer arrays and then print the equals out. I tried the Intersect method:

```
var checkingDuplicates = boughttickets.Intersect(winningtickets).Any();
```

and then used a `if`-statement:

```
if (checkingDuplicates == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You didn't win anything");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(checkingDuplicates);
}
```

However, the output always returns true with this `if`-statement.

I am truly sorry if i have some Spelling misstakes, my native language is not English.

Comment: Hey Rickard - you inadvertantly asked this question on the meta site. I took the liberty of migrating it here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still havent figured out where to post some questions.

Comment: Im so sorry for causing everyone trouble. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's really several questions you need answered. [Here's the documentation about the `Any` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx). Note that the return value is a boolean, i.e. true or false. [As Servy noted in their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23571302/173497), your inclusion of `Any` is extraneous, as `Intersect` already returns what you claim to want, "the equal numbers". As-is, this question isn't likely to be particularly helpful to anyone else, so I'm going to flag it to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i would say read the documentation. From your comment above, you can not call .toString() on IEnumerable withou defining .tostring implementation.
Try this

```
var checkingDuplicates = boughttickets.Intersect(winningtickets);

if (!checkingDuplicates.Any())
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You didn't win anything");
 }
 else
 {
   foreach(TICKET checkingDuplicate in checkingDuplicates)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("FETCH AND PRINT YOUR TICKET INFORMATION FROM TICKET OBJECT/CLASS");
   }
 }
```

In the foreach loop above TICKET is the type of object you are using on the IEnumerable lists above.

Answer (score 2):

`Any` takes a sequence of items and returns a boolean indicating if there are any items in that sequence.

You don't want to know *if* there are any items in that sequence, you just want to know what all of the items in that sequence are.  That means don't call `Any`, and you'll have your sequence of the intersection of those two arrays.

Comment: thanks, but...if i use my intersect variable `checkingDuplicates` and print it with .tostring() it returns System.Linq.Enumerable+<IntersectIterator>d__8b`1[System.Int32] instead of the equal numbers

Comment: @RickardB. That's correct.  The sequence itself has not overridden `ToString` to print out the items that the sequence represents.  You need to actually iterate the sequence and print out each item yourself.

Comment: So i make a .ToArray() instead of .Any()? Or is that not necessary?

Comment: That is not necessary.

Comment: i got this error while trying to iterate the sequence:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Comment: @RickardB. And that message is of course entirely correct.  You cannot get items using an indexer for an `IEnumerable`.  You should use a `foreach` to iterate an `IEnumerble` instead of accessing items by index.

Comment: Using `ToArray` is not necessary, but it improves performance. If you don't you will be creating the result twice, first once to check if there are any items in it, and then again when you iterate it.